# Implication of "for a half year"

Tags: sentence-usage

In a conversation with one of my friends, I said:

> I have been working at XXX company **for a half year**.

In fact, I was trying to convey I have been in this position for half a year and I'm still there now.

Well, what turns out is, the sentence made him feel I was not working at the XXX company any longer as the time I said it.

In the end, he corrected me with "I have been working at XXX corporation **for half of a year**.".

I am unsure if "for a half year" in the sentence has that implication?

Also, I am wondering what the correct way to express the ideas/implications:

1. I have been working at XXX company for some years, and I have left/am leaving now.
2. I have been working at XXX company for some years, and I am still working there.

Comment: I still wonder, what's the question? The title? The conclusion of your post? :)

Comment: @MaulikV "the correct way to express the ideas/implications" , 1 and 2. Also I am unsure if "for a half year" has that implication.

Comment: Why invite complexity? Say *six months!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have been working at XXX company for **a half year**.

According to [half-year](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/half-year), it seems to be commonly used as a hyphenated modifier, not a standalone noun.
By saying:

> I have been working at XXX corporation **for half of a year**.

you break up the phrase into a fraction and a noun. So this version is OK.
As an option, to me (AmE), I would consider this more natural:

> I have been working at XXX corporation **for half a year**.

I don't know if there is a grammatical basis for "half a year", but if you say "for half of a year" really fast, you're likely to drop the *of*.

In the case where you worked there in the past and it already ended, then:

> I **had been working** at XXX company for half a year, (but **I left** because my boss **was** irrational).

In the case where you worked there in the past but it is just ending now, then:

> I **have been working** at XXX company for half a year, but **I am leaving** because my boss is irrational. (*this one requires additional context*)

In the case where you worked there in the past and are still working there, then:

> I **have been working** at XXX company for half a year.

"half a year" by itself only indicates a period of time.

Comment: "Half a year" sounds the most natural option to me too (as a BrE speaker).

Comment: Thanks for that correction. But this did not answer my questions above.

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: Why did my friend think I had left the company as the time I said by "I have been working at XXX company for half a year."? He is an American by the way.

Comment: I am an American, too. You would have to ask him, though it may be just his perception of what you meant (implied meaning).